# How to create a startup command?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, startup, xset

How do I create a startup command permanent on every cycle restart ?
As previously having brightness reset when set at power saving mode to turn off the monitor.

- 18.04 64bits 5.4.0-42-generic
- Desktop Nvidia 440 driver

I found out xset dpms 600 900 1800 works on turning off the monitor display but I wanted it to run at startup which i do no need to type manually on the terminal.

I tried adding xset dpms 600 900 1800 to the bottom of home/.profile but it didn't work.

Further testing and by adding an extra line to run terminal by adding

```
xset dpms 600 900 1800
gnome-terminal
```

at the terminal startup checking the `xset -q` xset dpms was not set `Standby: 0 Suspend: 0 Off: 0`  while it should be `Standby: 600 Suspend: 900 Off: 1800`

**The weird scenario** is when manually launch a terminal without typing anything , the command of `xset dpms 600 900 1800` active.

What would it be the reason ?
.profile with command 'xset dpms 600 900 1800'
Not trigger on startup
but when I launch terminal manually it trigger the command.

If anyone could explain the reason ? or a better way to run the command on startup rather running on .profile ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/500147/480481

Comment: The display manager doesn't necessarily load your `.profile`. LightDM does, I think, but GDM hasn't done that for a while.

Comment: @pomsky , the startup askubuntu.com/a/500147/480481 does not work.Does it work on 18.04.5 ?

Comment: It should work. If it doesn't for you, consider editing your question with details and full content of the `.desktop` file.

Comment: @pomsky my script https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JmGmqcsjwF/  at autostart sh.desktop https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gWB6bktHrF/ .

Answer (score 0):

The X Server, which listens for the `xset` command, starts *after* login.

Place the command in a script, and put the script in your ~/.config/autostart/ directory. It will run every time the X Server is started for your account.

Comment: I paste the script `#!/bin/bash
# Turn off Monitor
xset dpms 900 1200 1800
exit` and save as .sh , chmod it 776 still it does not run.Just tell me , is my script wrong ? Just a simple command line. @user535733